# Advantages of compiled BLAS and Lapack vs Accelerate.framework BLAS and Lapack on Mac os Pro M2?

Tags: macos, lapack, blas

As mentioned above, I want to use either the accelerate.framework BLAS and Lapack or compiled for my R, to run certain statistical calculations more efficiently, and want to check if one version is better than the other?

Comment: So install one and run tests, then install the other and run tests - make sure the base system is identical for each.